# Interacting with an AVR Microcontroller on a Mac

Tags: macos, avr, avr-gcc, atmel, freertos

I have recently purchased the [ATiny84 microcontroller](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11232) and I was wondering if I could upload code to it from my Macbook Pro that runs snowleopard. Specifically, could I run c files and FreeRTOS?

Comment: @H2CO3 How could I do this? I am very new to this.

Comment: @userXXX Install the avr-gcc toolchain and compile the C files, then use avrdude to upload them to the AVR.

Comment: @H2CO3 Will I need an SD Card to save the complied files onto?

Comment: @H2CO3 Is there a video or tutorial of someone doing this?

Comment: @userXXX Why would you need an SD card? And yes, there are plenty of tutorials, just google "avr programming tutorial". And use written tutorials, YouTube videos suck.

Comment: @H2CO3 All of the tutorials that I have are either for [windows](http://hackaday.com/2010/10/23/avr-programming-introduction/) or [Outdated](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/setup-mac.html)

Comment: AtTiny84 (or any Tiny) might be too small for FreeRTOS, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As H<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub> suggest you can use [avr-gcc and avrdude](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/) but I hope you're familiar with C/copiling/setting up path variables in osx.

If you're only getting started with embedded programming I recommend having a look at the [Arduino](http://arduino.cc) project. It's very easy to get started. Also, for your particular chip(ATiny 84) have a look at [this guide from MIT](http://hlt.media.mit.edu/?p=1695):

[image: diagram]

[image: tiny programmer]

[image: Arduino board definition]

Comment: @H2CO3 ^_^ no worries, thanks for the vote. are you really 18 ? your programming skills look impressive.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks. Yep, I'm really 18. Had I been older, would I have more time for programming... :(

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Just to be sure...The Attiny84 can function withour arduino right?

Comment: Yes, you can continue without an Arduino board, that's just an option. Still you will need an ISP (which what you can use an Arduino for), but as listed in the article the other options are: [AVRISP mkII](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?category_id=163&family_id=607&subfamily_id=760&tool_id=3808) / [USBtinyISP](http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/) or [TinyProgrammer](http://hlt.media.mit.edu/?p=1801)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I only ask because I am trying to make a personal [wristwatch](http://www.besportier.com/archives/wrist-watch-concepts-iwatch-clock-1.jpg) from scratch.